# Asp.net Checkboxlist design/multiple values

Tags: asp.net

I'm having trouble designing a dynamically populating checkboxlist that displays three different values, as you can see in the first example. It's supposed to be a checkbox that displays three fields. Here is the code

```
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <table class='main-table' style="position: relative;">
                    <tr class='header-table'>
                        <td>Account</td>
                        <td>Store</td>
                        <td>City</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkStores" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Vendor_Selected" CssClass="checkbox" Style="margin-left: 10%;">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>
```

[image: Employer Example]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLRNH.jpg 
"How the Checkboxlist is supposed to look while displaying 3 different values."

The code above is what it supposed to look like, three fields populating with information. The code below is what it actually looks like.

[image: My attempt]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLRNH.jpg
"What it actually looks like, displaying only the first item.text = srd["field"].ToString();."

Here's how I'm adding values on the backend

```
                    ListItem item = new ListItem();
                    item.Text = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                    item.Value = sdr["Dist_num"].ToString();
                    chkStores.Items.Add(item);
```

I guess my confusion lies in my thinking I could just string together the item.Text but changing

`item.Value = sdr["Dist_num"].ToString();`

to

`item.Text = sdr["Dist_num"].ToString();`

Just overwrites the first item.

Answer (score 0):

I cheesed it by just concacting strings together like

```
item.Text = sdr["Name"].ToString() +  "  "  + sdr["Name"].ToString() +  "  "  + sdr["Name"].ToString();
```

It's ugly and poorly formatted but it accomplishes what I need.